# ES6 destructuring preprocessing

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

## Problem

Function arguments destructuring is an amazing feature in ES6.
Assume we want a `function` named `f` to accept an `Object` which has an `a` key

```
function f({ a }) {
    return a;
}
```

We have default values for the case when parameter wasn't provided to a function in order to avoid `Type Error`

```
function f({ a } = {}) {
    return a;
}
```

This will help in the following case

```
const a = f(); // undefined
```

Though, it will fail on

```
const a = f(null); // TypeError: Cannot match against 'undefined' or 'null'.
```

You can see how Babel transpiles the function to ES5 [here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=env&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=function%20f(%7B%20a%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20a%3B%0A%7D).

## Possible solutions

It can be avoided by arguments validation and preprocessing. In `Python` I could use decorator, but in JS we don't have them standardized, so it's not a good idea to use them yet.
Though, assume we have a decorator `checkInputObject`, which makes needed checks and provides default values using given items list (or tree for the case of nested destructuring).
We could use it in the following way without `@` notation

```
const f = checkInputObject(['a'])(({ a }) => a);
```

It could look like this with `@` notation

```
@checkInputObject(['a'])
function f({ a }) {
    return a;
}
```

Also I can make all needed actions in the function itself and only then use destructuring, but in this case I lose all advantages of function arguments destructuring (I'll not use it at all)

```
function f(param) {
    if (!param) {
        return;
    }
    const { a } = param;
    return a;
}
```

I can even implement some common function like `checkInputObject` in order to use it inside of the function

```
const fChecker = checkInputObject(['a']);
function f(param) {
    const { a } = fChecker(param);
    return a;
}
```

Though, using of additional code doesn't look elegant to me. I'd like to have not existent entities be decomposed to `undefined`.
Assume we have

```
function f({a: [, c]) {
    return c;
}
```

It would be nice to get `undefined` in the case of `f()`.

## Question

Do you know any elegant and convenient way to make [nested] destructuring resistant to nonexistent nested keys?

My concern is following: seems like this feature is unsafe for using in public methods and I need to make a validation by myself before using it. That's why it seems useless until used in private methods.

Comment: Use  `try ... catch`?

Comment: What exactly do you expect `checkInputObject` to do when the input doesn't match the expected format, to throw an exception? That's just what your code already does.

Comment: If you want to write a function that does nothing when called with invalid arguments (`if (!param) return;`), you should write that explicitly. Such functions are rarely needed anyway.

Comment: @Bergi At the of the "Possible solutions" section of the question I've written that I'd like to have `undefined` for not destructured values just like for ordinary arguments which were not provided. E. g., when you call `(a => a)()`, it will return `undefined` and will not fail, so I wished to have similar behavior for destructuring of items which were not provided.

Comment: @Charlie But if you call `(a => a.prop)()`, it will fail. Yes, you always can add syntax to accept even more values without failing, but why would you do that? I don't see the point in writing an "always silently ignore failures"-function.

Comment: All your examples do only one thing: fetching and returning a single value at a specific path in some nested structures. Is that the full task at hand, that you want to solve with the destructuring mechanism, or is there more? Because this can be solved way easier with a simple utility function.

Comment: @Thomas I've used as simple example as I could leaving it valid. The simpler examples of my question are `(({ a } = {}) => ())()` and `(({ a } = {}) => ())(null)`, though it doesn't use the `a`, and `ESLint` doesn't appreciate this.
More real use is quite simple: if I write a module, I need to avoid destructuring in public methods in order to throw more informative errors than default ones in the case of destructuring impossibility. It confused me and I want to find out whether that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to handle this in ES6 is to respect the way params are being processed by the language and shape API to fit it better, not in the opposite way.

The semantics behind destructured argument in `fn(undefined)` is that the argument will be replaced with default value, in the case of `fn(null)` means that nully argument won't be replaced with default value.

If data comes from the outside and should be conditioned/preprocessed/validated, this should be handled explicitly, not by destructuring:

```
function fn({ foo, bar}) { ... }

fn(processData(data));
```

or

```
function fn(data) {
  const { foo, bar } = processData(data);
  ...
}

fn(data);
```

The place where `processData` is supposed to be called is totally on developer's discretion.

Since proposed ECMAScript decorators are just helper functions with specific signature, same helper function can be used both with `@` syntax and usual function calls, depending on the project.

```
function processDataDecorator(target, key) {
  const origFn = target[key];
  return target[key] = (...args) => origFn.apply(target, processData(...args));
}

class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.method = processDataDecorator(this, 'method');
  }

  method(data) {...}
}

class Bar {
  @processDataDecorator
  method(data) {...}
}
```

And the way that the language offers since ES5 for default property values is `Object.assign`. It doesn't matters if `data` is `undefined`, `null` or other primitive, the result will always be an object:

```
function processData(data) {
  return Object.assign({ foo: ..., bar: ...}, data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! The most meaningful part for me is `The proper way to handle this in ES6 is to respect the way params are being processed by the language and shape API to fit it better, not in the opposite way.`. Examples are useful, but I've explained such approaches in general in my question.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, if you have control over data that is passed to a function and no sanitizing is necessary, it's just as simple as following conventions for destructuring.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `try...catch` and use that in a generic decorator function:

```js
function safe(f) {
   return function (...args) {
       try {
           return f(...args);
       } catch (e) {}; // return undefined
   };
}

function f({ a } = {}) {
    return a;
}

f = safe(f);
console.log(f(null)); // -> undefined
console.log(f( { a:3 } )); // -> 3
```

Comment: In other words, you propose using of decorator/wrapper as I've mentioned in the question, right?

Comment: this is the best generic solution for such an issue, but it should be used with caution. @Charlie this solution is generic for all types of nested/non-nested destructures, unlike the one you proposed in the question.

Comment: It is indeed a decorator, but it does not take the final argument like in yours, but the function. This is a generic decorator. Make sure your function handles errors well, otherwise the outer `try ... catch` will kick in, and mask other errors that may occur.

Answer (score 2):

I believe i can help you solve this problem by showing you a different way to look at it.

The problem you are facing is not about destructuring, because you will face it in any function that you are sending it different types that its expecting.

to solve such issue, ex. de-structuring, you can use type checking solution, such as [Flow](https://flow.org), which statically checks for types, hence it will fail at build time whenever you are sending wrong things to the function.

the essence of javascript is that its a dynamically types language, hence you might want the function to be able to work with any parameter sent to it, in this case, you can use dynamic type checking, the solutions are many.

the function parameters are more of an "agreement" to how you use the function, rather than accessing its parameters (after all you can just use `arguments` to access them), hence by sending different things you are violating this agreement, which isn't a good practice anyways, its better to have 1 function that does 1 thing, and accepts as few complicated parameters as possible.

Comment: You mean that JS doesn't need to have some elegant solution for the issue, right? I've thought about this but I thought that I may be wrong and an alternative solution is going to appear.

Comment: type checkers are the solution, but not native to javascript at this moment. javascript is meant to be dynamic, hence it should deal with different types, but to be able to youre gonna have to use if/switch statements, i recommend having pure functions that do small things, accept the argument in `a` directly for example, this problem will disappear then

Answer (score -3):

didn't you just answer yourself the question you ask?

I think default param is more elegant way for this.

```
function f({a: [,c]}={a:[undefined,undefined]}) {
    return c;
}

f();
```

Comment: Try to call `f(null)` and it will not set default argument value

Comment: `a` will never be `[undefined, undefined]` unless there is nothing sent to the function.

Comment: @digitake right, in order to use deep assignment of default arguments you should use `({ a: [, c] = [3, 4] } = { a: [1, 2] })`. Though it will fail on `null` provided